# Python print line of Csv removes double quote

Tags: python, csv

When I print the line, it removes the double quotes for instance this csv:

a, "b", c

prints like

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

but i want to print like

```
['a', '"b"', 'c']
```

python:

```
import csv

f_in  = csv.reader (open('source.csv', 'rb'), quotechar='"')

fields = []

for line in f_in:
    fields.append(line)

    print line
```

any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: removing quotechar='"' didnt change anything

Comment: Which version of Python are you using (and which OS)?  I actually get the output you're asking for just running your program against the line of input you gave using Python 2.7 on Windows.

Comment: I am using Python 2.6 with Debian 6.. @Gerrat

Answer (score 0):

To treat quoting characters as regular characters, use [`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE)

```
import csv

f_in  = csv.reader (open('source.csv', 'rb'), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

fields = []

for line in f_in:
    fields.append(line)

    print line
```

Comment: The OP just needs to be aware that if there are quoted fields due to embedded field delimiter, then there may be some "incorrect" results